# Periodically change views

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

I'm trying to create an activity that consists of multiple layouts (imagine newspaper sections like 'News', 'World News', 'Sport'...and so on) that periodically change their content. So every x seconds a different news story is shown.

What's the most efficient way to do this in android?

I started out with my own layout. And just updated the different TextViews and ImageView programatically. That worked fine, except for image loading, as for the lack of view recycling the image was reloaded every time a certain story was displayed. This caused a noticeable lag (even when using Picassos image caching) as all the layouts were updating their news story at the same time.

Than I looked at ViewFlipper. Now I inflate multiple layouts programatically (one for each news story) and add it to the ViewFlipper (one for each news section). Once that is done everything runs pretty smoothly. But it takes ages until all those layouts are inflated.

So what's the best way to go here? I couldn't find any good examples online but maybe I'm just missing the right term to google for.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a looping ViewPager. A ViewPager typically will preload the side of the pages when the current page is displayed, so that reduce the lag. There's a library for that. https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager. Hope this helps.